# Application specfic data in DXF Entities

Tags: dxf

I'm looking for a way to tag entities (for example [arc](http://www.autodesk.com/techpubs/autocad/acad2000/dxf/arc_dxf_06.htm)) in a DXF with an numeric ID of my choosing. Is there a good (standard complient) way of doing this?

Looking at the DXF format reference, I see there is a "common group code" *102* that is documented as "application defined codes". Can I use that? If so an example of the correct way to use it whould be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After asking a [similar question on the autodesk forums](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2013/DXF-Application-defined-codes-in-entities/m-p/3780379/), I have found that I can use [Extended Data](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2011/ENU/filesDXF/WS1a9193826455f5ff18cb41610ec0a2e719-7943.htm) to add my numeric ID.

Extended Data is appended at the end of the entity and in my case I will solve it by appending the following:

```
1001
MYAPP
1002
{
1070
    12
1002
}
```

- Where 1001 marks the start of extended data
- 1002 marks the beginning end end of list
- 1070 is a 16-bit integer

It's also possible to add extended data from Autocad software using the command _xdata